# How to configure the URLmanager rules correctly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii-url-manager

I can't configure routing project in Yii is 3 days, all tried to help ...
I have:

/var/www/ - project

/var/www/yii - yii framework

**./htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is http://localhost/begin/, use /begin/

RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

index.php finds.

./var/www/protected/config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=>array(
              '/'=>'/view',
              '//'=>'/',
              '/'=>'/',
            ),
    ),
```

When I enter for example 107.170.91.28/site/contact then displays an error 404.
URL of server 107.170.91.28
On the local server. all works. 
If I enter this URL 107.170.91.28/index.php/site/contact or 107.170.91.28/index.php?r=site/contact - it works.
Ask for help, because I tried all methods set.

Comment: place the .htaccess where index.php exist

Comment: why did you change your url rules?

Comment: /var/www/.htaccess in same folder with /var/www/index.php

Comment: I tried but I failed to properly configure. On the local server are such rules and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is happening only on server it is either because you have configured Apache to ignore .htaccess directives on your server, or because you do not have Rewrite module loaded/installed

Either you can configure the apache conf to turn on by changing in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (location may be different depending on OS , you can of course turn it only for application directory only as well

```
<Directory>
...
        AllowOverride None
....
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory>
...
        AllowOverride All
....
</Directory>
```

for enabling rewrite module you can do ( may vary depending on OS)

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP! The only other errors appeared (

Comment: np; if the answer helped you can select it then others with the similar problem will know how to approach it :)

Comment: btw i m not sure your rules array works properly.. i use this set of rules usually perhaps this  will fix your other problem "'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',"

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but nothing has changed. I have changed the rules.

Comment: Interestingly, this is due to the incorrect ' rules ' or something that links a Yii::app()-request-> > baseUrl?

Comment: sry about that.. it was worth a shot.. i wasn't sure on that part which is why didn't include it in the answer..